# Trouble getting height of OverlayItem Drawable

Tags: android

I'm having some trouble getting a hold of the drawable a certain OverlayItem is using so I can calculate the height of it and properly offset the note that shows onTap. Here is my code to try to get that drawable:

```
Drawable marker = item.getMarker(android.R.attr.state_focused);
if (marker != null) int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

marker ends up null.

I'm using a drawable XML file with a selector for the different states of the OverlayItem's drawable. In it I'm specifying a drawable for the null state, state_focused, and state_pressed.

Thanks for any help!

-Nick

Comment: I don't understand "marker ends up null". There is a problem loading/resolving drawable or getting height?

Comment: Yeah there seems to be a problem getting a handle on the drawable. The drawable loads up onto the screen right but trying to grab it programatically to then calculate its height isn't working. In the above code the if(marker != null) part is never running, so item.getMarker() must be returning null. Sorry for not being more clear in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/el/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem.html#getMarker%28int%29) about getMarker:

> Returns the marker that should be used
>   when drawing this item on the map. A
>   null value means that the default
>   marker should be drawn.

Therefore all you need to do is to pre-calculate the height of the default marker, store it somewhere and return it in case null is returned.

I have also find this [discussion](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/09/09/maps-itemizedoverlay-and-you/) about OverlayItem and ItemizedOverlay useful.